# Issue with com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart library

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, androidx

Hi I have a problem with com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart library I want to add to my project when I sync my project everything is ok but when I compile my project it appears this error and I don't know why.

The problem says: `More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'`

It supposed that I put everything in the right place

build.gradle (Module app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "company.eduardo.administradorfinanzas"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0-alpha'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'

    // Room components
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"

// Lifecycle components
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And my build.gradle (Project)

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
    roomVersion = '1.1.1'
    archLifecycleVersion = '1.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

either use a [stable version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.PhilJay/MPAndroidChart):

```
dependencies {
    // implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2"
}
```

or limit the duplicate `androidx-annotations.pro` to one entry:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst "META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro"
    }
}
```

also check the `libs` directory, if not the duplicate entry originates from a `*.jar`, because file `androidx-annotations.pro` sounds as if it were a ProGuard consumer rules file, as it is often being provided by a library. and the `google-services` plugin currently would be at version `4.1.0`.

Comment: Where shoulld I put the pakingOptions in the build.grade app or build.gradle prokect ?

Comment: @EduardoNoyola into the module's `build.gradle`, into the `android` configuration there. still think that you may have added duplicate dependencies, because there is no other logical explanation, for the file existing twice (or more than once). there's barely need to add any `*.jar` files, because the dependencies are being fetched & cached.

Comment: It says: C:\Users\Carolina\AndroidStudioProjects\AdministradorFinanzas\app\build\intermediates\transforms\mergeJavaRes\debug\0.jar:The process do not have access to the file because is being use for other process

Comment: @EduardoNoyola kill the gradle daemon and delete `app\build`. there might be a permission issue, eg. that it cannot remove previously built files from there.